# identifying keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + W) press in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to write a certain script that will trigger when the window close shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>) is pressed.
This works fine for IE as well as Firefox but doesn't work at all for Chrome.
I am using the below code for doing the same.
Please suggest me if there is a better and more proper way of doing it.

```
var prevKey = ""
$(document).keydown(function (e) {//Enter and F5 button press
    if (e.keyCode == "116" || e.keyCode == "13") {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    }//Ctrl + w
    else if (e.ctrlKey == true && e.keyCode == "87") {//FOR CTRL + W
        alert("Ctrl + W");
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }//(Ctrl or Alt) + F4
    else if ((e.ctrlKey == true || e.altKey == true) && e.keyCode == "115") {
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
    }
```

Comment: cant you put like this `if (e.keyCode == "116" || e.keyCode == "13") { window.onbeforeunload = null; } else {window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;}` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot...
just had complicated the thing a bit instead of straight forward approach...
Thanks  again @CerlinBoss

Answer (score 1):

Try to check for click event on Window object and check if the keyCode is equal to keyCode of <kbd>W</kbd>, then check if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is clicked.
This part of snippet has worked on FF and Chrome for me.

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    // check for W button
    if (e.which == 87) {
        // check if CTRL is clicked!
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            alert('gg');
        }
    }
});
```